# Getting DOM tree of XML document

Tags: python, xml, dom

Does anyone know how I would get a DOM instance (tree) of an XML file in Python. I am trying to compare two XML documents to eachother that may have elements and attributes in different order. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, whenever possible, I'd start with [elementtree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (preferably the C implementation that comes with Python's standard library, or the [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) implementation, but that's essentialy a matter of higher speed, only). It's not a standard-compliant DOM, but holds the same information in a more Pythonic and handier way. You can start by calling `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`, which takes the XML source and returns an element-tree; do that on both sources, use `getroot` on each element tree to obtain its root element, then recursively compare elements starting from the root ones.

Children of an element form a sequence, in element tree just as in the standard DOM, meaning their order is considered important; but it's easy to make Python sets out of them (or with a little more effort "multi-sets" of some kind, if repetitions are important in your use case though order is not) for a laxer comparison. It's even easier for attributes for a given element, where uniqueness is assured and order is semantically not relevant.

Is there some specific reason you need a standard DOM rather than an alternative container like an element tree, or are you just using the term DOM in a general sense so that element tree would be OK?

In the past I've also had good results using [PyRXP](http://www.reportlab.org/pyrxp.html), which uses an even starker and simpler representation than ElementTree. However, it WAS years and years ago; I have no recent experience as to how PyRXP today compares with lxml or cElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions to ponder:

- [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)
- [amara](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Amara) (xml data binding)

Comment: I've looked at minidom and there isn't any information in the documentation on how to get a DOM tree from a parsed file. I'd like to compare two trees so that order doesn't matter. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: The minidom documeentation in Python 2.6 gives an example of getting a DOM from a file (are you after something else )

    from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

    dom1 = parse('c:\\temp\\mydata.xml') # parse an XML file by name

Answer (score 0):

For comparing XML document instances, a naive compare of the parsed DOM trees will not work. You will probably need to implement your own NodeComperator that recursively compares a node and its child-nodes with some other node and its child-nodes based on your specific criteria such as:

- When is the order of child elements significant?
- When is whitespace in text-content significant?
- Are there default values for some elements and are they applied by your parser?
- Should entity references be expanded for comparison

[Minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) is a good starting point for parsing the files and is easy to use. The actual implementation of the comparison function for your specific application however needs to be done by you.